# What is quicker performance wise? IE filters or a sprite/images

Tags: html, css, performance

I know its a bit of a stupid question because it depends on the size of the image/sprite etc, but could anyone give me an idea of what is quicker?

If you can give an answer, could you also describe how much quicker one is than they other and also any proof of this e.g. articles etc.

Many thanks in advance,

B

Comment: Sprites. I can't imagine any alternative being faster than that (once the file is loaded), including Base64. You've also got more performance tuning options (such as how the sprite file is compressed, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Sprites are apparently slightly faster because you make fewer http requests; but I don't have any stats for you.

The only place where you will notice significant performance improvement is if you have pictures which change when you hover over them.  If you use separate images then the browser will wait until the first image is hovered over before it even starts to download the second image.  If you use sprites then the second picture is already loaded so will appear instantly.

Comment: Yeah but why would filters involve making a sepearate http request? ..... I should have specified earlier this is based on having a fallback for css3 elements for Internet Explorer e.g. rounded corners on buttons

Comment: Filters won't.  I was just giving an answer because no-one else had.  Hopefully someone else will have more info for you.